# div contained ajax reload when a link clicked

Tags: php, jquery, html, reload, pjax

hi i am using ajax for loading pages, and also for back button facilities. everything is worked fine except one. Well i narrowed down my problem but cant get any solution. my main page has a container div where i load most of the pages without reloading the whole pages like in gmail.

as for pjax it also loads tags for seo friendly url.

but there is a div in the main page contains "`<?php echo $pagename; ?>`" it gets the pagename from the loaded page and showed it in the div. well it worked only if the browser reloads. otherwise when i open pages continuously it does not change, it shows the previous one.

so how do i fix this issue. i am thinking about refreshing the div that contains the pagename. so how do i do that?

Comment: hello guys! i really need help here.

Answer (score 0):

PHP code is always executed on the server side, so this div won't change when you use pjax. You need to change the pagename div manually as you do with the content div. You can do this with 2 pjax calls, or by splitting the ajax response into pagename and content (but maybe then pjax is not the right solution).

Comment: well i think pjax is more efficient and more modern solution of ajax itself. Except for IE support(well who cares for ie!), most of the latest browser, even most of the android and windows phone support pjax.

Comment: isn't there any simple method than this!! cause simpler is better. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can send a ajax request to the file that contains `echo $pagename` and display the response(which would be $pagename) using javascript.

Since you are using jquery, you can use [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for this purpose.

Here is the code

```
$.ajax({
    type = "POST",
    url = "your-php-file-path",
}).done(function(response){
    $("#div-id").html(response);
});
```

Comment: @Avik I have added the script in the answer.